# Scanning Strings with more than one word

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

I am having trouble creating a C program to scan more than one word at a time. I am creating a program to read sport team names and their number of wins and losses and their type of loss. There are 22 teams in total and each team name can have 1 to three words for their name, I am wondering what would be the best way I can scan my data to account to the varying name size. 
**My code that I have so far:**

```
int main(void) {

char name[25];
int win[25], losses[25], lossOT[25], lossSO[25], points[25];
int i, n, j, p, x, min;

setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

printf("Enter team data:\n");

i=0;
while(i<26){
    scanf("%s", name);
    if(0==strcmp(name,"0"))break; //what it to break not with a space but when a number is read

    scanf("%d %d %d %d",win[i], losses[i], lossOT[i], lossSO[i]);
    i++;
}
```

**Sample Input:**

```
 Team:               W    L   LOT  LSO
 Durham United       5    2    1    0
 Kingston Clippers   6    3    3    1
 London              9    2    1    4
 Ottawa Fury Academy 5    3    1    6
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing first, `while(i<26)` is [off-by-one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) for your array size, use `i < 25` to stay within the bounds.

Then, you can use [`fgets()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to read a certain amount of data into buffer, delimited by a newline, which is also stored in the buffer.